# Translating a letter grade into a number grade

Tags: c++

So im having some trouble with one of my assignments. I need to have the user enter in a letter grade (B, B+/-) and have that be converted into a number grade (3, 2.7). i can get the program to work with just A,B,C but i cant figure out how to get the program to work when the users adds a +/- to the grade. This is what i have so far.

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string input;
   string A;
   string A-;
   //string B+;
   string B;
   //string B-;
   //string C+;
   string C;
   //string C-;
   //string D+;
   string D;
   //string D-;
   string F;

   cout << "Enter a letter grade: ";

   cin >> input;
   if (input == "A")
       cout << "The numeric value is 4.0" <<endl;

   if (input == "A-")
       cout << "The numeric value is 3.7" << endl;

   if (input == "B+")
       cout << "The numeric value is 3.3" << endl;

   if (input == "B")
       cout << "The numeric value is 3" <<endl;

   if (input == "C")
       cout << "The numeric value is 2" <<endl;

   if (input == "D")
       cout << "The numeric value is 1" <<endl;

   if (input == "F")
       cout << "The numeric value is 0" <<endl;

   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the variables `A`, `B`, etc. Also, `string A-;` is not a valid declaration. You can simply remove them.

```
int main()
{
   string input;

   cout << "Enter a letter grade: ";

   cin >> input;

   if (input == "A")
       cout << "The numeric value is 4.0" <<endl;

   ...
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. i guess i was putting too much thought into it

Comment: @Aaron, glad I was able to help.